# Alert de Sucesso

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho um modal para marcar amigos, quando o usuário clica em marcar, chamo o onclick que faz a requisição para o controller.

Quero mandar uma mensagem de sucesso para o usuário, tenho uma div com display none e quero torná-la visível quando ocorre o POST.

Porém, com o POST a página é recarregada e a div volta a ser display none sem nem aparecer a mensagem.

```
 <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="display:none;">
  Amigo marcado!</div>


function marcar(e){

        $.ajax({
          url: '/MarcarAmigo/MarcarAmigos/',
          type: "POST", 
          cache: false,
          data: {'publicacao': publicacao, 'amigos_marcados': amigos_marcados},
          success: function () {
            $(".alert").css("display", "block");
          }
        });    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Opa, tenta dar um prevent defaults

```js
function funcaoComAjax(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   alert("SEM RELOAD");
   // FAZ TUA REQUISIÇÃO AJAX
}
```

```html
<a href="https://pt.stackoverflow.com" onclick="funcaoComAjax(event);">Clica</a>
```

**[edição]**

Fiz um fiddle usando jQuery (não que seja obrigatório) com a ideia do comentário, coloca o prevent default no submit do form e faz a requisição ajax com os dados do form
https://jsfiddle.net/evandrobm/xpvt214o/876386/

Comment: Isso não serve porque preciso do POST para a requisição no servidor e salvar os dados no banco de dados, é um button submit pois preciso do submit.

Comment: Tu pode colocar o preventDefault no submit do form, fazer o ajax com os dados do formulário, e no retorno do ajax fazer a mesma coisa

Comment: @BiancaC. editei a resposta com um exemplo

Comment: @BiancaC. isso resolveu o teu problema?

Comment: Não, como eu disse o e.preventDefault() tira a função submit do meu form

Comment: Mas tu precisa que o formulário seja submetido? Achei que a ação do formulário era feita pela requisição AJAX

Comment: Qual o action do teu form e o que ele faz? E essa URL `/MarcarAmigo/MarcarAmigos/`chamada no Ajax faz o que?

Answer (score 0):

O exemplo abaixo mostra o seu código exibindo a div de sucesso a executar o ajax com sucesso.

```js
function marcar(e) {

  $.ajax({
    url: '/MarcarAmigo/MarcarAmigos/',
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    data: {
      'publicacao': publicacao,
      'amigos_marcados': amigos_marcados
    },
    success: function() {
      //fadeIn() ou show() faz aparecer uma div oculta
      $(".alert").fadeIn()
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Botão para chamar o evento da função ajax -->
<button onclick="marcar()">Executar Ajax</button>

<!--Sua div de sucesso oculta-->
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" hidden>
   Amigo marcado!
</div>
```